# how to set x and y coorinates android

Tags: java, android

i have created a 10x10 grid in the center of the screen in android, now i would like to give each square in the grid a coordinate. for example top left square in the grid would be 0 then 1, 2,3 and so on. But i dont know how to do this. i am trying to do this in a draw class which extends view. my code of what i am trying is below

```
public int coordinates(int posX, int posY){

        int startX = (screenWidth / 2) - (rectSide / 2);
        int startY = (screenHeight / 2) - (rectSide / 2);

        //for(int i=0; i<=10000; i+=100){
        xCoord = (startX + (posX*100));
        yCoord = (startY + (posY*100));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You know you start at point **0,0 top left**. So assuming you have equally spaces squares you can just do the `screen height / 10` to get how far apart each square should be in the **y direction**. And then do the same for the **x direction**. Say your screen was **1000 pixels tall**.

Then your grid at `position (0,1)` would be at `(0,100) pixels.` `(0,2)` would be `(0,200)` you are just multiplying the **y coordinate by the height** of each square in the grid.